# Generate lines from points in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have two lists of coordinates,

```
lat = [-23.23, -44.23, -12.23]
lon = [-21.23, -14.23, -62.23]
```

and I generate a tuple of `lat long` pairs with `zip`:

```
latlon = zip(lat, lon)
```

and that gives the expected result. Now there is a very common pattern of generating lines with the points. It is common to do something like

```
    line_coords = []
    for i in xrange(len(coords)-1):
        line_coords.append([tuple(coords[i]), tuple(coords[i+1])])
```

so the result is now a list of tuples, each tuple an list of beginning and end of a line:

```
line_coords
[[(-23.23, -21.23), (-44.23, -14.23)], [(-44.23, -14.23), (-12.23, -62.23)] ]
```

and it get worse if the line needs to come back to the beginning. This looks like an anti-pattern. Is there a name for this pattern and a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to codereview! As it is, your question is off-topic because the code is broken. Didn't you mean `latlon` instead of `coords` ?

Comment: More, what version of Python would you like to be used when somebody will review your question ?

Comment: @Dex'ter There is nothing that requires the two snippets to be that related. For what it's worth, `latlon` could be passed to a function defined along the lines of `def whatever(coords):`.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to iteration in Python, there is often an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) or function that come close to the needs.

Here, I’m thinking about `pairwise` which is defined as:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

If you’re interested in cycling back to the beginnig, you should consider [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) too:

```
def get_line_coordinates(iterable, close=False):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...
    ends with (sN, s0) if close is True else (sN-1, sN)
    """
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    if close:
        b = itertools.cycle(b)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

Lastly, [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) will let you fill that last value by consumming less memory than `cycle`:

```
def get_line_coordinates(iterable, close=False):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...
    ends with (sN, s0) if close is True else (sN-1, sN)
    """
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    beginning = next(b, None)
    if close:
        return itertools.izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=beginning)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```